# Need help decoding a WAV file email attachment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, decode, wav, google-app-engine-python

I am using Google App Engine for the infrastructure and I am trying to decode an attached .WAV file and decode it to string for passing on to google cloud's speech-to-text api.

Here is my code, I am at a loss as what to do. I tried to decode using 'base64' or the "encoding property in the payload" but I keep getting this error: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 4: invalid continuation byte"

The .WAV file that I use for testing is decoded correctly using online wav to base64 decoders but for some reason it doesn't work with this code.

```
def receive(self, mail_message):

    if hasattr(mail_message, 'attachments'):
        file_name = ""
        file_contents = ""
        for filename, filecontents in mail_message.attachments:
            file_name = filename
            file_contents = filecontents.payload.decode(filecontents.encoding)
```

Comment: Can't you pass the bytes directly like `RecognitionAudio(content=filecontents)` ? Why decoding it?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

@snakecharmerb 

<html><head></head><body><div class="yahoo-style-wrap" style="font-family:Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;"><div>dsf</div></div></body></html>
------=_Part_4218024_179197831.1558180999159--
------=_Part_4218025_939837478.1558180999161
Content-Type: audio/wav
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="brooklyn.wav"
Content-ID: <7ae68c46-0b02-9b5f-8fb4-9681ff0be54f@yahoo.com>

Comment: @LukaszTracewski Good point, but i am using HTTP api, so need to decode it string/base64 for json format. :( But yeah, if I can't get it to work, i'll probably use client libraries

Comment: Maybe then `base64.b64encode(filecontents)`? I don't know if this could be any inspiration, but here's how I am working with WAV on AWS: https://github.com/tracek/audio-explorer/blob/cb9f70067ff58e71ed407aa735bb9ff8412a688e/audioexplorer/audio_io.py#L75

Comment: @LukaszTracewski: Just tried, didn't get the error but speech to text api is complaining. I checked the base64 string generated online, seems very different from base64.b64encode(filecontents). 

{
   "error": {
     "code": 400,
     "message": "Invalid recognition 'config': bad encoding..",
     "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
   }
}

Comment: Based on your previous answer, aren't your file already in base64? --> ` Content-Type: audio/wav Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition`

Comment: Thanks, @LukaszTracewski, Looks like the obvious was staring at my face, the attachment is indeed already in base64... lol. 

But now i only noticed that it has /r/n every certain number of strings, seems like the original wave file was chopped in pieces and put together with /r/n. I can fix it with string maniplation functions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JamesChing I am going to put it as the answer then, please mark it as resolved. Good luck further down the road!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filecontents` does not need any decoding: it's already in in proper format (encoded as `base64`) and ready for further processing with speech-to-text api (as discussed in the comments section).